# Is conn field in OpenLDAP log unique?

Tags: ldap, openldap, syslog

I want to figure out how many authentication failed or success by processing OpenLDAP(2.4.42)'s log file.

Following is the sample of my OpenLDAP's log.

```
slapd[5516]: conn=2803 op=3 SRCH base="ou=groups,dc=myOrg,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=*)
slapd[5516]: conn=2803 op=3 SRCH attr=objectClass cn userPassword gidNumber memberuid modifyTimestamp modifyTimestamp
slapd[5516]: <= bdb_inequality_candidates: (modifyTimestamp) not indexed
slapd[5516]: conn=2803 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
slapd[5516]: conn=2803 op=4 SRCH base="dc=myOrg,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=ipService)(cn=*)(ipServicePort=*)(ipServiceProtocol=*))"
slapd[5516]: conn=2803 op=4 SRCH attr=objectClass cn ipServicePort ipServiceProtocol modifyTimestamp
slapd[5516]: conn=2803 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
slapd[5516]: conn=2797 fd=37 closed (connection lost)
slapd[5516]: conn=2795 op=23 UNBIND
slapd[5516]: conn=2795 fd=36 closed
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 fd=36 ACCEPT from IP=10.1.1.205:49974 (IP=0.0.0.0:636)
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 fd=36 TLS established tls_ssf=128 ssf=128
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=1 SRCH base="ou=people,dc=myOrg,dc=com" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(objectClass=*)(uid=xyzUser))"
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=1 SRCH attr=uid
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=2 BIND dn="uid=xyzUser,ou=people,dc=myOrg,dc=com" method=128
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=2 BIND dn="uid=xyzUser,ou=people,dc=myOrg,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=2 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=3 BIND anonymous mech=implicit ssf=0
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=3 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=3 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=4 SRCH base="ou=people,dc=myOrg,dc=com" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(&(&(&(&(objectClass=myOrgEmployee)(status=TRUE))(webmailAllowed=TRUE))(passwordExpired=FALSE))(uid=xyzUser))"
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=4 SRCH attr=uid
slapd[5516]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (passwordExpired) not indexed
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
```

What I want to know that value of `conn` attribute in log is always going to be unique or not? Because my algorithm is like

1. Search for keyword `SEARCH RESULT`
2. Get value of attribute `conn` and `op`
3. Find for `SRCH base` same value of `conn` and `op`

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's the BIND request that get's used during authentication.

Otherwise your authentication system uses another user (Directory Manager perhaps?) or anonymous requests to match the username / password against the directory server.

Indeed you're actually authenticating using BIND:

Connection / LDAPS estabilishment:

```
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 fd=36 ACCEPT from IP=10.1.1.205:49974 (IP=0.0.0.0:636)
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 fd=36 TLS established tls_ssf=128 ssf=128
```

Bind using the provided credentials:

```
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=2 BIND dn="uid=xyzUser,ou=people,dc=myOrg,dc=com" method=128
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=2 BIND dn="uid=xyzUser,ou=people,dc=myOrg,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
```

Result is successful (err=0):

```
slapd[5516]: conn=2804 op=2 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
```

So, the way how i would implement the search is:

- Get a list of accepted connections including client IP:PORT:
- Match the lines with the same connection number and a BIND request, from there get the operation number
- Match the result line for the previous bind request using both the connection number and operation muber and check the result using the error code returned.

But very probably you'll have easier ways that openldap logs to do what you need, if you're using a prebuilt IAM like Siteminder / Oracle (ex SUN) Identity Management you'll find it's easier to get login info from there. If not you can check your application logs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found out that connection id gets reset after restarting OpenLDAP.